# spring boot - com.mysql.jdbc.spring boot exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'customer0_.email' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables User and Customer which extends from User in MySQL implemented in Spring Data JPA and a simple REST controller I created to test posting data to the database.

**User**

```
package mk.klikniobrok.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

/**
 * Created by andrejnaumovski on 12/8/16.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class User {
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int enabled;
    @Column(name = "date_created", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    @Column(name = "last_used")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date lastUsed;
    @Enumerated
    private Role role;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(
            String username,
            String password,
            int enabled,
            java.util.Date dateCreated,
            java.util.Date lastUsed,
            Role role
    ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.lastUsed = lastUsed;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Column(name = "date_created")
    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_used")
    public java.util.Date getLastUsed() {
        return lastUsed;
    }

    public void setLastUsed(Timestamp lastUsed) {
        this.lastUsed = lastUsed;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

**Customer**

```
package mk.klikniobrok.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by andrejnaumovski on 12/8/16.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends User {
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    public Customer(String username,
                    String password,
                    int enabled,
                    java.util.Date dateCreated,
                    java.util.Date lastUsed,
                    Role role,
                    String email,
                    String firstName,
                    String lastName,
                    String imageUrl
    ) {
        super(username, password, enabled, dateCreated, lastUsed, role);
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_used` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  CONSTRAINT `customer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `user` (`username`)
)
```

Using Postman to send a POST request to the controller, this is the response I get:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1481218619875,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
  "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
  "path": "/customer/"
}
```

The error I am getting is: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'customer0_.date_created' in 'field list'

I've checked most answers on StackOverflow but the problems appear to happen on join table and other more complicated operations, not something as simple as this. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the schema of the table?

Comment: and what is the API doing?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I have added the schema to the original post. The API is only making a simple POST save to database through a CrudRepository.

Comment: just a doubt, if you have two tables why you used discriminator? I guess you are clear about its presence.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I have edited the code accordingly to what I think it should look like except now I'm getting an error on another field, 'customer0_.date_created'.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by changing the @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) to @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) on the User class.